# What happens when you combine multiple datatypes in an atomic vector in R programming language?

Tags: r, vector

I tried running a code to identify the type of the vector produced while combining different data types. **Here is the code and what I got as the output.** Can somebody explain why this output is seen?

`v<-c(1L,2,TRUE)`
`typeof(v)`

**Output: [1] "double"**

Comment: Read this [testing-and-coercion](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#testing-and-coercion)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is the rule:

**When you attempt to combine different types they will be coerced in a fixed order: character → double → integer → logical. For example, combining a character and an integer yields a character.**

Answer (score 0):

An atomic vector can only hold values of a single data type. If you put several different types in it, these get coerced to a common type. In your case `double`.

IF you want to keep the data type of the original values, you need to use a `list`. Lists do not have this restriction.